# Is that possible to send sms text message via VBA

Tags: vba, sms

I have to monitor some stock prices movement and apply some equations on excel for checking some ratios. The problem I have is sometime I would be out of office but still try to keep an alert about the change and I wonder if it's possible to use VBA to send text msg. Thanks

Comment: Not without using a third-party service like https://www.twilio.com/

Comment: Since services like twilio.com requires money, a better alternative would be to send email instead of sms

Comment: thanks, i wonder if it would work if i set up some conditional email, like once some ratio breach then it would send out an email as alert

Comment: How about `.To = "Joe Joe <8008008000@tmomail.net>"` Or `mms.att.net` should work